# SiteFinity: What is the easiest way to include the contents of a local file in a Content Block?

Tags: sitefinity

Is there an easy way to include the contents of a local txt snippet file within a content block in a siteFinity page? A bit like the old HTML server-side includes (I'm assuming that wouldn't work!)

```
 <!--#include virtual="../quote.txt" -->
```

Anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way to display the contents of a file from a content block.

You could probably do this with javascript/jquery if you expose the file through the webserver so it is accessible from the client side, with something like this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/9377/load-text-file-in-javascript.aspx

If you need to protect the file, your best bet is probably to create a simple user control (.ascx) that uses the System.IO.File to read from the server, then register this control as a widget to drop on any page.

Just be sure that you cache the file otherwise it'll read from the file system every time and create a bottleneck on your page.

hope this is helpful!